# Spring Contract Maven Plugin pushStubsToScm does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I tried to use Spring Contract Maven Plugin in a **producer** side to upload the stubs jar and share it with consumers.

I am using Spring Cloud Contract 2.0.0.

I configured the **spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin** in my project, [the codes is uploaded to Github](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-cloud-sample/tree/master/contract-producer-rest-git).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <basePackageForTests>com.example.demo</basePackageForTests>
        <baseClassMappings>
            <baseClassMapping>
                <contractPackageRegex>.*rest.*</contractPackageRegex>
                <baseClassFQN>com.example.demo.RestVerifierBase</baseClassFQN>
            </baseClassMapping>
        </baseClassMappings>
        <!-- We want to pick contracts from a Git repository -->
        <!--<contractsRepositoryUrl>git://file://${project.basedir}/target/contract_git/</contractsRepositoryUrl>-->
        <!-- Example of URL via git protocol -->
        <!--<contractsRepositoryUrl>git://git@github.com:spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples.git</contractsRepositoryUrl>-->
        <!-- Example of URL via http protocol -->
        <!--<contractsRepositoryUrl>git://https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples.git</contractsRepositoryUrl>-->

        <contractsRepositoryUrl>git://https://github.com/hantsy/contracts-git.git</contractsRepositoryUrl>
        <!-- We reuse the contract dependency section to set up the path
        to the folder that contains the contract definitions. In our case the
        path will be /groupId/artifactId/version/contracts -->
        <contractDependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </contractDependency>
        <!-- The mode can't be classpath -->
        <contractsMode>REMOTE</contractsMode>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <!-- By default we will not push the stubs back to SCM,
                you have to explicitly add it as a goal -->
                <goal>pushStubsToScm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I ran command `mvn clean install -DskipTests -DcontractsRepositoryUsername=hantsy -DcontractsRepositoryPassword=mypassword` and got the failure.

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/hantsy/contracts-git.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
```

**Update**: If I set `contractsMode` to LOCAL, it will fail with downloading stubs jar error, maybe similar with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120041/sprign-cloud-contract-consumer-side-can-not-find-stubs-from-local-maven-repos), in the new version 2.0.0, Spring Cloud contracts can not resolve jars from Local maven repos as expected when **stubsMode** is set to LOCAL.

**Update 2**: I also tried to add *contractsRepositoryUsername* and *contractsRepositoryPassword* in spring contract maven plugin config, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contractsMode` needs to be `REMOTE`. I've taken your example and it works well with:

```
<contractsRepositoryUrl>git://git@github.com:marcingrzejszczak/contracts-git.git</contractsRepositoryUrl>
<contractsMode>REMOTE</contractsMode>
```

with passing the credentials manually I see sth absolutely bizarre...

I see `[INFO] Passed username and password - will set a custom credentials provider` which means that username and password got passed and I'm using them. But actually what I get is `Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered`, which makes no sense. Can you file another bug for that? The workaround is to use the agent.

UPDATE:

The issue got fixed here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/678

Comment: In my local machine,the Git clone action is done successfully, but when it tried to push and got failure.

Comment: what if my contracts are with producer only, but the generated stubs should be published to a repository?

Comment: Please read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/using.html#flows-cdc-contracts-stubs-git